# Prevent console title change when click in console in a python script

Tags: python-3.x, windows, windows-console

Recently I tried to change the console title from my Python script to show some status to user. What I tried to use is as simple as below, and it works just fine:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW('Here Is My Custom CMD Title!!')
```

This will show "HERE IS MY Custom CMD Title" in the console window title bar, but it has some kind of malfunction. When I click anywhere in the console, it will change to something like "Select Here Is My Custom...".

I want to know is there any work around for this to prevent the title from changing on click?

Comment: The console's quick-edit mode is enabled, so when clicking on the console window, it activates text selection mode, which causes various console API functions to block and modifies the window title. You cannot control this temporary title change in select mode. It's part of the console UI. What you can do is programmatically disable quick-edit mode. Without it, selecting text in the console requires the user to manually enter mark mode.

Comment: FYI, I edited your question to remove all mistaken references to CMD as the console. cmd.exe is just a console application. It's no different from python.exe in that regard. Run python.exe directly from Explorer, and it will create a console, exactly the same as cmd.exe does. The console is a system resource, and in Windows 7+ this is implemented by an instance of conhost.exe for each console.

Comment: @ErykSun not sure conhost.exe is relevant in Windows 11 anymore, in Task Manager everything is called Terminal.